# Strange problems driving an Optocoupler (PC123) with a Nano

Tags: arduino-nano, led

I'm having some strange issues getting a Nano to drive a PC123 optocoupler properly.

What I'm trying to do: In the real world, I need to press a button ONCE, and have the device that I'm connecting this too, see FIVE quick button presses... (Input 1 press, and Output 5 presses, at the timing I set in the code). I am using a mix of LED "Blinking / Flashing" code to do what I need.

My connection of the Opto seems fine. It works perfectly if I run this "BLINK" code: (With the PC123 optocoupler connected to Pin13):

```cpp
// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(200);                       // wait for a while
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(200);                       // wait for a while
}
```

When I run this, the Optocoupler turns ON and OFF as I need, and the device I am controlling is happy, but it obviously runs forever as I have no counters or anything.. (This proves my hardware is good at this point!)

But, when I try this following code, with the exact same hardware circuit, the output goes HIGH as soon as I ground Pin2, and it stays HIGH! It holds the optocoupler ON and there is no ON/OFF or "blinking or flashing". BUT, it only does this when the OPTO is connected (there is load) on the Nano output. If I disconnect the Opto, the Pin13 LED will flash as expected. And my code seems to work fine (on the on-board Pin 13 LED).

VERY interestingly and very strangley though, when the "power-up" Pin 13 LED flashes (i.e- when you power cycle the Nano, or press the reset button) this will trigger the Opto ON/OFF perfectly! But when the code starts to run, via my Pin 2 input switch, with the Opto connected to the Nano, the output locks HIGH again! What the!?

```cpp
int ledPin = 13;   // LED is connected to digital pin 13
int switchPin = 2;   // switch connected to digital pin 2
int switchValue;   // a variable to keep track of when switch is pressed
int counter = 0;

void setup()    
{    
      pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);   // sets the ledPin to be an output
      pinMode(switchPin, INPUT);   // sets the switchPin to be an input
      digitalWrite(switchPin, HIGH);   // sets the default (unpressed) state of switchPin to HIGH
}    
      
void loop()   // run over and over again
{    
    
    switchValue = digitalRead(switchPin);   // check to see if the switch is pressed
      if ((switchValue == LOW) && (counter <= 1)) {   // if the switch is pressed then,
          for(int ii = 0; ii <= 5; ii++)   // 7 = 4 flashes, 5 = 3 flashes, etc
      {
          digitalWrite(ledPin, !digitalRead(ledPin));
          delay(100); // Length of the flashes in ms
          counter++;
      }
    }
      if (switchValue == HIGH)
      //if ((switchValue == HIGH) && (counter > 2))
      {
           counter = 0;
           delay(100); // Debounce
           
      }
}
```

I have tried filtering capacitors, diodes, resistance, pull-ups, pull-downs, everything I can think of and I am at a loss. Can anyone help me out? I'm thinking its a code issue (because I am an Arduino noob - please be gentle!), or a maybe a deficiency in the hardware of the Nano? FYI, I have done all of this on different Input and Output pins with the same results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you have `digitalWrite(switchPin, HIGH)` which activates the internal pull-up resistor

Comment: Yes, but isn't that required for my LOW switch (D2) to trigger the code? Otherwise it will float? 

Also, it works with no load (with the Opto not connected). It will flash the Pin 13 led fine. But with the load on the output (Pin13 - or any other pin I choose), the output goes HIGH when the code runs and stays HIGH.

Comment: I tried changing digitalWrite(switchPin, HIGH)  to LOW, and also removed it all together. Regardless of this, triggering the D2 input always results in the same thing... 

Is the counter code correct? Maybe its getting stuck in the counter loop somehow??

Comment: just a note about comments in code ..... `digitalWrite(switchPin, HIGH);   // sets the default (unpressed) state of switchPin to HIGH` ... the comment is misleading ... while it is technically true, because it enables the pullup resistor, a beginner programmer may think that `digitalWrite(switchPin, LOW);` sets a default state of the pin to LOW

Comment: why aren't you using the same code to blink the led in the second program? ... the second program makes an assumption about the state of the output pin ... `set` the state instead of `inverting` previous state

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand the pull-up code and the pin state as a result. That's all ok.

Why am I not using the blink code that works? Because it doesn't do what I need.  I'm a new and I don't know how to make that code start and stop using a momentary button input, and to have it only flash *five times* when I do press that button... 

If you can help me with that I would be most grateful. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thank you @DrG** for your excellent reply! I really appreciate the time you have taken on this. I will answer your questions here:

- What am I trying to do? I am adding the Nano to a Ham Radio Transceiver, that can change frequency (via button presses on the microphone) in only 1kHz, or 10kHz frequency steps. What I am doing here, is by adding this Nano to the microphone button circuit, and selecting the "1kKz" step option, I will get a "5kHz" step! This is great for searching for SSB signals quicky (1kHz is slow, 10kHz is too big and you miss some!). So, I press 1 time, the radio will step 5 times. This is the purpose of my project. :)
- How have I wired it up? **Exactly** the same as you have shown, and I have also used both D13 (not recommended as you said, and D10 (as you have used in your proposed answer).
- Your code is great, and I really like that it will use D13 to show what it's doing on the LED, and use D10 to drive the Opto. GREAT!

Now - here is the crazy part... Even with your code, and the exact circuit (other than my PC123 vs your 4N25 (I have 4N35's here too), I get exactly the same problem I had before! As soon as the Nano drives the Opto, regardless of the GPIO I configure, it locks HIGH! The D13 LED flashes as expected, but D10 goes high and never goes low again, until a reboot or power cycle...

I now believe that even my original code is fine (not the best way to do it, but still functional) but my NANO is faulty! It's an "ELEGOO NANO" clone. And I think it's the issue!!!

Your input is not wasted as I will use your code, it is much better than mine! :) I am going to get a new NANO and try this again, and now I am pretty confident that with a new Arduino, this will work! I will report back and let you know how it goes.

Best regards,

Pez

Answer (score 0):

I confess that I am not sure what you are trying to do, but I have an idea and I hope this helps. First, there are several Nanos and not all of them are AVR-based. I used an OLD Nano clone and even had to select the ATMega 328P (old bootloader) - it's been a while. I also used a 4N25 opto [this could make a difference, look at the data sheet for your device)..

You have not shown exactly how you have things wired up. Let's assume that it is like this - and I DO NOT think it is a good way of doing things (bear with me), and

[image: WRONG WAY]

Using this code, it works exactly as it should.

```
int ledPin = 13;  
int switchPin = 2;       
int nflashes=10;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(switchPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if ( digitalRead(switchPin)==HIGH) {
  for (int i = 0; i < nflashes; i++) {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, !digitalRead(ledPin));
      delay(100);
    }
    while (digitalRead(switchPin) == HIGH); // wait until switch is released
  }
}
```

The opto turns on with D13 lighting the added LED and the onboard LED also turns on. Note that the onboard LED is dimmer because you are driving TWO LEDs ; the onboard one attached to D13 and the LED inside the opto and you have no current limiting resistor on the opto LED. I'm not sure if you have it wired this way but if so, in my view, it is not a good way of doing things.

Apart from that, think about what happens when you hit reset...my guess is that the ATMega sets all GPIO to input AND the boot loader initializes the onboard LED to an output and apparently flashes that LED - I am guessing and have not gone through the code. I notice that with the above scheme, I see both the new LED and the onboard LED flash once briefly on reset, as I would expect.

Hooking up the switch as I have shown (pulled to ground) will eliminate any problems from floating states during a reset. It will only be read HIGH when you press the switch after you initialize the GPIO.

---

I would put the opto on a separate GPIO like this:

[image]

...and using this slightly modified code

```
int ledPin = 13;  
int switchPin = 2;  
int optoPin=10;      
int nflashes=10;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(switchPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(optoPin, OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {
  if ( digitalRead(switchPin)==HIGH) {
  for (int i = 0; i < nflashes; i++) {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, !digitalRead(ledPin));
      digitalWrite(optoPin, !digitalRead(optoPin));
      delay(100);
    }
    while (digitalRead(switchPin) == HIGH); // wait here until switch is released
  }
}
```

Everything works fine and the new LED does not flash during a reset and nothing gets stuck.

I wish you had show exactly what connections you made and I apologize if I missed some point.

Again, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @DrG for your excellent reply!  I will answer your questions in a new "answer" because I can't type enough characters here...